# Finding an optimal positive definite matrix analytically

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, optimal-control

I have a cost function $f= a^TK_P^TK_Pa + b^TK_Pa$, where $a$ and $b$ are known user defined 3*1 real valued vectors and $K_P$ is an unknown real valued $3*3$ positive definite matrix. Could anyone give me an analytical method to find the optimal matrix $K_P$ to minimize the above cost function using Lagrange multipliers method?

The fact that $K_P$ has to be positive definite, is troubling me as that inequality constraint is real hard to incorporate. I'd really appreciate if I find an easier way.

Comment: If you don't have further constraints, you don't need The Lagrangian. The set of positive definite matrices is open. Just derivative $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $a\ne 0$.

**There is a minimizer if and only if $a^T b < 0$!**

Let $f(K) = a^T K^T K a + b^T K a$. Then, we have
$$ Df(K)[H] = 2 a^T K^T H a + b^T H a = \operatorname{tr}((2Kaa^T + ba^T)^T H ),$$ 
that is
$$ \nabla f(K) = 2Kaa^T + ba^T. $$

Now, if the gradient vanishes at a positive definite $K$ it follows
$$ a^T b = -2a^T K a < 0. $$

On other hand **one** solution is given by
$$ Ka = -\frac12 b. $$
Define
$$ K = \left(I - \frac{ab^T}{a^T b}\right)^T \left(I - \frac{ab^T}{a^T b}\right) - \frac12\frac{bb^T}{a^T b}. $$
Then, $K$ is positive definite and
$$ Ka = \left(I - \frac{ab^T}{a^T b}\right)^T (a - a) - \frac12 b = -\frac12 b. $$

Comment: Is $a^T b < 0$ is both necessary and sufficient? And is $Ka = -b/2$ for the gradient to vanish? Could you explain these points?

Comment: @MonimoyBujarbaruah $a^T b < 0$ is indeed necessary, as otherwise the minimizer is not positive definite. The condition is also sufficient, as I give you an explicit construction for **one** minimizer. there might be more, as $f$ is convex in $K$ but not strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And did you notice the second query? I guess $Ka=-2b$ was a typo in your solution.

Comment: @MonimoyBujarbaruah oh yeah. Thanks. It should be $Ka=-\frac12b$. You need to change $K$ accordingly.